# Simple triangulation over flat torus

Tags: computer-science, triangulation

This is somewhat of a computational question: let me know if it is inappropriate.

I have a flat torus with sone random points marked.

I would like to compute a triangulation of said torus such that my points are the vertexes of the triangulation.

A bit of googling has not given me any results. My naive idea would be to start from the fully connected graph, and every time two edges cross, simply remove one of them. Unfortunately this looks like it's going to be quite expensive, as I have $n^2$ edges each of which can potentially intersect all of the others. I also looked into the Delauney triangulation, but I am not sure it would work on an generic torus, and moreover I have no idea on how to implement it successfully. It also seems rather overkill, since I do not need my triangulation to have any special property.

Is there a simple, greedy way to get a triangulation in non-prohibitive time?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it really significant that we are on a torus? What would you do with the same problem on a plane?

Comment: Well, a torus is compact while a plane is not. I would like to eventually generalize this to a generic surface, so I picked a torus to avoid plane-specific solutions.

Comment: Do you want a _good_ triangulation? It seems relatively easy to generate a triangulation in which many of the triangles could be very narrow.

Comment: Well, more of a "good enough" triangulation. This is mostly for testing a few ideas of mine, so ease of implementation is the first concern.

Comment: I see a possible impediment. If an edge is specified only by its two endpoints, with some kind of rules based on the relative positions of points to decide which way do draw the edge, it is possible that you put $n$ points on the torus in such a way that the complete graph on those $n$ points consists of a polygon of at least $4$ sides, plus additional edges inside the polygon. I think there is then no way to triangulate the portion of the torus outside the polygon.

Comment: Well, the torus is compact, so any polygon divides it in two regions each of which can be triangulated... I am afraid I don't see the problem you mention

Comment: Mathematically, of course, it can be triangulated. But it seems to me (unless I misread you) that you are not just doing math, but rather writing software. My question is how you represent the most general kind of segment in your software model. Presumably you have a coordinate map over the surface of the torus. Suppose you had two points very close together in coordinates. Mathematically, you can get from one point to the other in any of several directions. Can you distinctly represent each of those possible edges in your software?

Comment: To put it more concretely, I had in mind an answer that involved connecting points $A$ and $B$ with two edges so that the path $ABA$ (along both edges) cuts the torus into a cylinder. Can your software represent that path?

Comment: I am using geodesics on a flat torus, which are very conveniently just straight lines in its representation as a square with identifications, they simply need to wrap appropriately. So yes, I can represent those segments in my software, but that wouldn't be a valid triangulation: I need the triangles to have three distinct vertexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to construct a triangulation of $n$ points on the flat torus in $O(n)$ time by "brute force" as follows, at least if the points are in general position.  I'll assume we're working on the *square* flat torus, obtained by identifying opposite sides of an axis-aligned unit square.

First sort the points by their $x$-coordinates and connect them into a polygonal cycle $P$.  Then we can triangulate above $P$ by repeatedly cutting off a triangle $pqr$ whenever $p$ lies below the geodesic segment $pr$.  Similarly, we can triangulate below $P$ by repeatedly cutting off a triangle $pqr$ whenever $p$ lies above the geodesic segment $pr$.  This triangle cutting can be implemented in linear time using a stack, similar to the [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) convex hull algorithm.

After both these phases, we have triangulated the points on the square flat *cylinder* obtained by identifying the left and right sides of the unit square.  The top and bottom edges of this triangulation are closed horizontal geodesics, passing through the "highest" point $a$ and the lowest point $z$.  To complete the toroidal triangulation, we can extend two diagonals upward from $a$ to $z$.

In the following figure, the heavy black segments show the initial polygonal cycle $P$, the edges of the upper triangulation of $P$ are red, the edges of the lower triangulation of $P$ are green, and the final two diagonals between the highest and lowest points of $P$ are blue.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The flat torus can be constucted by identifying the opposite sides  of a square in the plane.

Take an element in center of such a square and an element at the middle of each side. Draw a segment between the element in the center and the corners of the square, and between the element in the center and the elements in the middle of each side. This induces a triangulation of the torus.

You can generalize this for the $n$-torus which can be constructed by identifying opposite face of a parallepiped, triangulate each face  such that no point is identifyied in the quotient and draw a segment between a point in the center and the vertices of the triangulation on the faces.

Comment: I need my triangulation to have vertexes on specific assigned points.